# react native with firebase validation input field

Tags: firebase, react-native

I want to validate my login form in `react native`. but i used another **Firebase** logging function in `onChangetext` in react native. 
This is my `onPress` function in the login button press.

```
  async onLoginPress() {
    this.setState({ errorMessage: null, loading: true });
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    console.log(email);
    console.log(password);
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        // this.props.navigation.navigate("Friendlist");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        //var errorCode = error.code;
        //var errorMessage = error.message;
        this.setState({
          error: 'AUTHENTICATION FAILED',
          loading: false
        });
      });
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("email", email);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("password", password);

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({
          loading: false
        });
      }
    });    
  }
```

and this is my `onChangetext` define in `TextInput`

```
onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
```

I want to add validate functions with these functions. how caI i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple functions in the onChangeText callback as

```
onChangeText={async email => {
  await method1()
  await method2()
  ...
}}
```

but I would recommend you to use callback since you're using `setState`. This ensures the `setState` is updated before the callback in it is called

```
onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email }, () => this.validate(email))}
```